# What to use: In or of?

Tags: british-english

"We will pay dearly for this mistake in/of priorities"

What is more correct, in or of?

Comment: Neither. You need to replace "mistake" with a different word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly between the two prepositions, *in* would sound more natural.

However, neither really sounds natural in the first place.

It would be better to rephrase the sentence:

> We will pay dearly for our mistaken priorities.